# How to use the Subquery Syntax of SQL Server to Join the Two Table Together and Remove Duplicates?

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have two tables are structured as follows,

Table a

```
province_id
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
3
.
.
.
```

Table b

```
f_name       city_value        label
 city_id       1            Austin
 ac_id         1            Mayor: Jason Lee
 df_id         1            Republican
 ef_id         1            Property tax is high
 city_id       2            Dallas
 dfg_id        2            Mayor: ABC
 fth_id        2            Republican-3
 tpr_id        2            Property tax is low
city_id        3            Waco
 ddd_id        3            Mayor: DEF
 ers_id        3            Republican-4
 qws_id        3            Property tax is middle
city_id        4            Arlington
 zxg_id        4            Mayor: HGR
 zUg_id        4            Republican+4
   .
   .
   .
```

1. The first table is called `a` and it just has 1 column `province_id`.
   (It has duplicates and almost 1500000 rows and the unique value is almost 200)
2. The second table is called `b` and it has 3 columns:
   (the "b" table is a longitudinal data and the total row is almost 400000)

- column 1 in table b is called `f_name` and the value of this variable is linked with column 3 `label`.

For example, when f_name=city_id and city_value=1, then label`l=Austin (city name).
When f_name=city_id and city_value=2, then label=Dallas (city name).
When f_name=city_id and city_value=3, then label=Waco (city name).
When f_name=city_id and city_value=4, then label=Arlington (city name).

- column 2 in table b is called `city_value` and it has duplicates as well like `province_id`. For example, for a specific city "Austin", its city_value is 1.
- column 3 in table b is called `label` and the content under this variable is about the information of the city specific to a province.

Within each `city_value`, the cell content of the variable `label` is unique. Among all cells within each `city_value`, the city name (e.g., Austin) is of interest.

What I want is this:

1. For table "a", please remove the duplicates of `province_id` column
   After deduplicates, table a should look like this

```
Table a
    province_id
    1
    2
    3
    .
    .
    .
```

2. As for table "b", please just keep all data records that have `city_value` and the city name;
   After deduplicates, table b should look like this
   Table b

```
    f_name       city_value        label
     city_id       1            Austin
     city_id       2            Dallas
     city_id       3            Waco
     city_id       4            Arlington
       .
       .
       .
```

3. Join the results of (1) and (2) together using the common key (deduplicated `province_id` and `city_value`) and the resulting data record should be equal to the number of deduplicated `province_id`.
   In fact, the unique province_id is just about 200 while the total rows after deduplicas is still 200000 or so. In other words, the range of total rows for table a after deduplicates is far less than that of table b.
4. If I want to get the same results, how can I write a CTE (common table expressions) code to do this with SQL Server?

It is evident that the cities such as "Austin","Dallas","Waco","Arlington" is what I need.

My code below is not correct because the duplicates is still there after joining the two tables.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.province_id, b.label
       FROM a
       JOIN b ON 
        a.province_id=b.city_value;
```

Comment: *It is evident* no it isn't

Comment: add a row_number and select a the rn = 2

Comment: Could you please write the whole code? I am a beginner and really don't know how to do this. Thank you!

Comment: how do you get the number 190 for Austin?

Comment: I rewrite the whole post.

Answer (score 1):

You can first remove all unwanted rows from your tables

```
SELECT a.province_id, b.label
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT province_id FROM a) a
       JOIN (SELECT city_value,label FROM b WHERE  f_name = 'city_id') b ON 
        a.province_id=b.city_value;
```

or at least remove all duplicates form Table a

```
SELECT a.province_id, b.label
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT province_id FROM a) a
       JOIN b ON 
        a.province_id=b.city_value
WHERE  f_name = 'city_id';
```

Comment: Both code doesn't work.

Comment: which error exactly? and what means not working?

Comment: Your first code snippet can work normally. Sorry for the confusion I gave you.

Comment: i am quite certain it works see https://dbfiddle.uk/_l3X49WZ

Comment: Both codes works for me now. Thank you!

Comment: Could you please provide CTE code? Thank you.

Comment: Why? it is actually quite simple https://dbfiddle.uk/P59DcAhG

Comment: Thank you! It is completely the same as I did just now.

Comment: The team leader told me that the SQL code I used here (subquery) suggests that I totally don't understand subquery and CTE. I really got confused. I don't understand is OK. I don' t think the nice guy who kindly help me with this question don't understand. Team leader said the code can produce the expected results. However, you don't understand the CTE and subquery.

Comment: then he should explain wjat he means every cte in the fiddle is a subquery, there are correlated subqueries, which we can use, but the quesrion didn't specify it. A CTE is used here as it is normal, theb there are recursive CTE's but they don't apply here. only to triw in they don't understand CTE or Subqueruies is not enough, so how is the answer from your teamleader, if he has a btter one show us the answer

Comment: To be honest, I really appreciated your help and assistance with my question. I felt that the team leader's comment is nonsense-"Your code can produce expected results, however, your code shows that you totally don't understand what CTE and subquery in SQL SERVER is." How could that be? LOL.

Comment: you can always print of the manual about subqueries and CTE, and then ask to point out, what he menas

Comment: Sure. My understanding of your code is clear logic and very meaningful. Even though for a SQL beginner like me, I can pick it up in several minutes.